# Please explain statement in a book on Loop Quantum Gravity

Tags: vectors, geometry, linear-algebra, loop-quantum-gravity

In a book by Carlo Rovelli on Covariant Loop Quantum Gravity, I struggle to understand a statement  on Tetrahedron as follows:

[image]

1. What is the dimension of the matrix?
2. How to derive the given matrix component as $-1/2(detM)M-1$?
3. What is the "closure relation"?

Comment: My general suggestion with a problem like this is to try an example. Can you make progress if you start with a [regular tetrahedron](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RegularTetrahedron.html)? You should be able to work out the normal vectors and edge vectors, and check the matrix identity in your Q2 explicitly. Q1: the matrix is 3x3 (note the question says $a=1,2,3$). Q3: Eq 1.9 is the closure relationship. The reason it is called that is since adding the 4 $L$ vectors together gave you zero, rather than a new vector.

Answer (score 1):

Since no one is try to answer this, I try to work out it by myself using hint given by Andrew.

So, suppose I have a tetrahedron whose vertices are the points A (2, -1,-3), B (4,1,3), C (3,2,-1) and D (1,4,2).

The three vertices emanating from a common vertex A of the tetrahedron as AB , AC & AD respectively as (2, 2, 6), (1, 3, 2) & (-1, 5, 5).

The matrix result from the above vertices as follows:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 2 & 6 \\
1 & 3 & 2 \\
-1 & 5 & 5 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Determinant (as given by https://matrix.reshish.com/determinant.php):

44

This is the volume of parallelepiped of the given coordinates.

The inverse matrix:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac {5}{44} & \frac {5}{11} & \frac {-7}{22} \\
\frac {-7}{44} & \frac {4}{11} & \frac {1}{22} \\
\frac {2}{11} & \frac {-3}{11} & \frac {1}{11} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Determinant x matrix inverse:

$$
44 \cdot 
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac {5}{44} & \frac {5}{11} & \frac {-7}{22} \\
\frac {-7}{44} & \frac {4}{11} & \frac {1}{22} \\
\frac {2}{11} & \frac {-3}{11} & \frac {1}{11} \\
\end{bmatrix}
= 
\begin{bmatrix}
5 & 20 & -14 \\
-7 & 16 & 2 \\
8 & -12 & 4 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Then calculates the cross product of the vectors using https://www.mathportal.org/calculators/matrices-calculators/vector-calculator.php:

AB - AC $\vec v_1 = (2, 2, 6)$ and $\vec v_2 = (1, 3, 2) \to -14i + 2j + 4k $

AB - AD $\vec v_1 = (2, 2, 6)$ and $\vec v_2 = (-1, 5, 5) \to -20i -16j + 12k $

AD - AC $\vec v_1 = (-1, 5, 5)$ and $\vec v_2 = (1,3, 2) \to -5i +7j - 8k $

Arrange the above normal vector results into matrix:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
-14 & 2 & 4 \\
-20 & -16 & 12 \\
-5 & 7 & -8 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

The transpose of this matrix:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
-5 & -20 & -14 \\
7 & -16 & 2 \\
-8 &12 & 4 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

It can be seen that the matrix result of determinant times inverse matrix is to calculate the normal matrix.

The $-\frac{1}{2}$ factor is given in the Carlo Rovelli's book: Instead, we choose the four vectors $\vec L_a$, a = 1, ..., 4 defined for each triangle as $-\frac{1}{2}$ of the (outward oriented) vector-product of two edges bounding the triangle.